# Spring XMPP GCM inbound channel not invoking service activator function

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, google-cloud-messaging, spring-integration

Following is snippet from my spring xmpp integration configuration,

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:xmpp.properties"/>

    <int-xmpp:inbound-channel-adapter auto-startup="true" 
    payload-expression="getExtension('google:mobile:data').json"
    channel="xmppChannel"
     xmpp-connection="xmppConnection" />

        <int:service-activator ref="xmppMessageConsumer" 
        input-channel="xmppChannel"/>

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="xmppChannel" log-full-message="true"
        />
```

Here is my service activator definition

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;

import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class XmppMessageConsumer {
    private final List<String> xmppMessages;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(XmppMessageConsumer.class);
    public XmppMessageConsumer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        xmppMessages=new ArrayList<String>();

    }

  @ServiceActivator
   public void consume(Message<?> input) throws Throwable {
      String text = (String)input.getPayload();
      xmppMessages.add(text);
      LOGGER.info(text);


   }
```

From the logs i can see the message received by the channel however service activator function is not being invoked.

```
10:48:59 PM RECV (0): <message to="588523657007@gcm.googleapis.com" from="devices@gcm.googleapis.com" type="normal"><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">{"data":{"Hello":"How are you"},"time_to_live":0,"from":"dqWxVXwH7HU:APA91bFco6xelMctjv5nMgeAIiZtH7TCCMX5a6UZ-ae2yNkBxLh-zVqy32gm6bd1IC3pyKCEwnYOFiBn4au-4XvPn8TzTvikGUNfeQ_1RN_TMk-9dyJ2WtJXVr7RCn0AGynToTWCZ7oC","message_id":"1Id","category":"com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm"}</gcm></message>
```

My assumption is by defining payload expression, message parsing is taken care of by the framework . Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

With your current configuration, you have two subscribers to `xmppChannel` - the service activator and the logging adapter.

When you have two consumers subscribed to the same channel (`DirectChannel` by default) messages will go to the two consumers alternately - round-robin distribution.

If you want the file to go to both consumers, change it to a pub/sub channel.

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="xmppChannel"/>
```

If you turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.integration` you can follow the messages through the flow.

Comment: Thanks @gary, however now I noticed that the message is not being forwarded to my channel. The message received from the connection is being dropped for some reason. The log I noticed is from the connection. Do i need to implement GCM extension ? I assumed spring integration provides out of box support for gcm xmpp when we specify payload expression. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: If the message is dropped, it is likely your expression evaluates to null. You will get a log message saying so, if your log level is at least INFO. The expression looks ok to me; I suggest you use a debugging in the `ChatMessageListeningEndpoint` to see what's going on.